# Optimizing size of the apk file

Tags: libgdx

I am currently working on a mini game using libgdx 1.0 + box2d with no more than 4 screens.
My base virtual screen resolution is 854x480 and texturepacker i being used.

The apk file after compiled has about 2.2mb. After a closer look, I just noticed that there 3 folders in the lib folder with the "same" files totaling 1.2mb:

android

   lib

       armeabi

             libgdx.so

             libgdx-box2d.so

       armeabi-v7a

             libgdx.so

             libgdx-box2d.so

       x86

             libgdx.so

             libgdx-box2d.so

Well, I need the files libgdx.so and libgdx-box2d.so, but is it safe to get rid off some of them or they are there to support different target devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not the same files.. check their sizes.Every version is for a different platform and its not really safe to remove any of them.

**armeabi**: compatible with all the devices,kinda like a compatibility mode ,much slower cause does not offer platform specific optimizations.

**armeabi v7a**:offers hardware float operations and other things that improve performance.

**x86**:same as v7a but for x86 architectures.

Most of the devices will probably be able to run on just armeabi but much slower than on v7a or X86.

Comment: Doesn't Google Play strip out the unneeded ones at download time or am I remembering something else?

Comment: @Tenfour04 , I don't think Google Play strips anything out of the apk,if you check at /data/app(need root) where all of the installed apps exist and open one of the apks most of them contain both armeabi and v7a binaries.